# Why does moving WCF proxy from Silverlight into a portable class library require CreateChannel to be implemented?

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, portable-class-library

I have a WCF service which is called from a Silverlight UI. The proxy is defined in the Silverlight code and looks like this:

```
public class MyServiceProxy : ClientBase<IMyService>, IMyService
{
    public IAsyncResult BeginGetId(string name, AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState)
    {
        return this.Channel.BeginGetId(name, callback, asyncState);
    }

    public int EndGetId(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        return this.Channel.EndGetId(result);
    }
}
```

I now want to call the WCF from a different application which isn't in Silverlight. I thought I'd try to share the proxy by moving it into a portable class library which targets .Net 4 and Silverlight 5.

After moving the class, the interface now wants me to override CreateChannel:

```
protected override IMyService CreateChannel()
```

I'm confused what implementation I should be providing here. Is sharing the proxy in a PCL a sensible thing to do or am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this question is old now, but I ran into this problem recently and it took me a little while to find the answer, so hopefully this can help someone save some time.

If you target Silverlight in your PCL, then `ChannelFactory<T>` is not available to you and thus you must create your own implementation of `CreateChannel()` on `ClientBase<T>`.

If you want to avoid implementing `CreateChannel()` yourself, then you can only target .NET 4.5 and Windows 8 and/or Windows Phone Silverlight 8.

If you select Windows Phone Silverlight 7 or 7.5, it will automatically require Silverlight 4 and higher. Similarly, if you select Windows Phone Silverlight 8 but a .NET version below 4.5, it will automatically require Silverlight 5. Both will force you to provide you own implementation of `CreateChannel()`.

Targeting Windows Phone 8.1 completely removes `ClientBase<T>`, because `System.ServiceModel` is not available in Windows Phone 8.1.